# Setting iconColor on SymbolLayer

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-android

Using something like

```
val color =  PropertyFactory.colorToRgbaString(Color.parseColor(Color.MAGENTA))
mapSymbols.setProperties(
            PropertyFactory.iconImage(Expression.get("icon")),
            PropertyFactory.iconColor(color)
)
```

The color seems to have no effect in the actual icon color.

Is there anything else that needs to be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is something coming in version 6.3.0 of the MapBox Android SDK.

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/releases/tag/android-v6.3.0-alpha.1